# References on the difference between Dirac's and Von Neumann's approach to Quantum Mechanics (rigged Hilbert Space vs Hilbert Space only)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations, dirac-delta-distributions

I have not found any clear and comparative explanation between the Dirac and von Neumann versions of Quantum Mechanics (rigged Hilbert Space vs Hilbert Space only). I have found some short articles. Is there any book or extended explanation of the subject? It will help if the answer doesn't start with "I don't really understand your question" or something like that, or telling me that I have to study, or a lot of references, etc., etc.

Comment: Related post on MO.SE: https://mathoverflow.net/q/383952/13917

Comment: Because of the policy of this forum, who ever answer, most include comments or an explanation related to the subject.